# Generic extensions methods colliding despite different type trees

Tags: c#, generics

Assume that we have the following 4 classes in C#:

```
public class ClassB :ClassA
{

}

public class ClassA
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{

}

public class Class1
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

ClassA and ClassB for one type tree and Class1 and Class2 form another.

I create the following generic extension methods but constrain the generic type to a specific type:

```
public static class ClassAExtensions
{
    public static T Field<T>(this T opts, string field) where T : ClassA
    {
        opts.Field = field;
        return opts;
    }
}
public static class Class1Extensions
{
    public static T Field<T>(this T opts, string field) where T : Class1
    {
        opts.Field = field;
        return opts;
    }
}
```

In theory the following code should compile since only a single extension method can be used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instanceB = new ClassB();

        instanceB.Field("fed");
    }
}
```

However the compiler returns this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ClassAExtensions.Field(T, string)' and 'Class1Extensions.Field(T, string)'

Is this a bug with the compiler or with the code? It seems to me that the compiler should be able to determine which extension method to use based on the type contraints.

Comment: This is overkill of extension methods. Extension methods are used for specific type not to use as Generic method. If you really want Extension methods for `ClassA` it should be declared as `public static ClassA Field(this ClassA opts, string field)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked tons of times. Generic type constraints *are not part of the method signature*.

The compiler, when resolving the call, sees two identical candidates:

```
ClassAExtensions.Field<T>(this T opts, string field)
Class1Extensions.Field<T>(this T opts, string field)
```

It can't choose between the two, because both are equally valid and therefore tags the call as ambiguous.

Now the question could be: is this a reasonable design? Well, to put it mildly, there are mixed opinions about the issue. Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/) for more info on the subject.